# Python: Issue reading/writing mp3 file

Tags: python, python-3.x, mp3

I am trying to read the text data out of an mp3 file, and then save it to a different mp3 file in python. I DON´T simply want to move the file, as I will be trying to modify it´s contents in the future.

Here is my code:

```
encoding1="latin-1"
with open(path.get(),"r", encoding=encoding_1) as f:
    file=f.read()
...
...
with open("D:\\test\\music_2.mp3","w+", encoding=encoding_1) as f:
    f.write(file)
```

I already tried different combinations of .encode() and .decode() with latin1 and utf8, but that didn´t work either.

Here are some notes on my problem:

- The file I save has about 32.000 more symbols than the original one for some reason, even though it should have the exact same length
- I don´t get an error message, but the mp3 file is just noise, not music
- If I don´t use encoding="latin-1", there is an error message, usually already while reading the file
- In one of these error messages, there was a problem with the letter "ï"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mp3` files are not text files.  You need to open them as binary files, so that certain characters are not translated.  You also will not need to worry about encoding with binary files as you are dealing with binary data not text.  To open a file as binary you need to pass the a `b` to the file mode.  [open(file, mode)](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open)

```
with open(path.get(),"rb") as f:
```

You can then parse the file and get to the text data in the binary mp3 file.